# UICollectionView newspaper like layout

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uicollectionview

Can UICollectionView be flexed to dynamically render interfaces like this one below (Newsify for iPhone)?

[image]

Or can only predefined static layouts be rendered? I would want to layout based on the image dimensions (h x w), say small grids for small images and larger ones for big images, all decided at runtime based on the data I get from my datasource.

EDIT: Any good tutorials on complicated dynamic layouts like the one above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Can UICollectionView be flexed to dynamically render interfaces like
>   this one below (Newsify for iPhone)?

Yes.

> Any good tutorials on complicated dynamic layouts like the one above?

There are some nice ones in GitHub, like:

- https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout
- https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo
- https://github.com/aceisScope/WaterflowView
- https://github.com/njdehoog/NHBalancedFlowLayout

And from other places:

- http://www.binpress.com/app/pinterest-gridview-for-ios-masonryview/836

Raywenderlich as also a serie of posts related to that:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to some tutorials online? Where there are complicated layouts? Will update my question as well.

Comment: The tutorial does not exist at http://www.binpress.com/app/pinterest-gridview-for-ios-masonryview/836 :)