# Creating a grid view on iOS

Tags: ios

I need to implement a grid view with dynamically-changing images.

Most of the time, I use a `UITableView` to create a grid, but I run into memory issues if I have a large number of images.

In iOS 6, the `UICollectionView` was added, but I've never used it before.

What are some "best practices" and view subclasses to use when making a grid view so I don't have memory issues?

Comment: UICollectionView seems perfect for this.

Answer (score 25):

[`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) is available in iOS 6.0 and later, so it can't be used if you want to support earlier versions.

There are quite a open-source libraries that let you create grid views:

- [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView)
- [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)
- [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)
- [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView)
- [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)
- [WCGridView](https://github.com/wess/WCGridView)

I am currently using `AQGridView`, and I've found it to be the most robust. It works just like a `UITableView`. Evadne Wu created a [video](http://vimeo.com/46408155) and [sample project](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) showing how to use it.

Also, if you're trying to do this without using Interface Builder, keep in mind that it'll be a bit more difficult since you have to create the views programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

I would go with `UICollectionView` as you said. You can actually see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131102/uicollectionview-newspaper-like-layout/15131134#15131134) I gave, where you can see already made libraries.

Comment: will UICollectionView support on older Devices?

Comment: @DeepakKhare:UICollectionView is available on iOS 6+.  I would no longer bother supporting anything less than iOS6 given the amazing uptake (93% of all devices on iOS 6+) so go with UICollectionView.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) and it backwards compatible with iOS 5 and iOS 4.3. UICollectionView is iOS6+ only. It virtually has the same API as UICollectionView.

[GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) is also a popular choice for creating grid views.

Comment: I have also used PSTCollectionView and it's pretty solid.  However, if you don't need backwards compatibility with iOS 5 or earlier I recommend using UICollectionView instead.  There are *plenty* of samples and tutorials on the Internets.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a UICollection view.  Since you've never used one, here is a good tutorial to follow: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but we have opensourced our commercial datagrid component and its free to use!

https://github.com/flexicious/iOSDataGrid

Its actually quite versatile in what it can do as compared to most libraries listed above.

http://www.ioscomponents.com/Home/IOSDataGrid