# How to show a table inside a uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've been searching a way to show a table, with mutable number of columns and lines, inside a uitableviewcell to present data.

I don't know if i'm searching in the wrong place or there isn't a easy to achieve this.

[image: Table]

I need to put something like this inside a uitableviewcell.

What I'm willing to do is to put a uiviewcollection inside a uitableviewcell and build a customlayout with headers and limit the number of columns and in some way control the flow of cells displayed inside this uicollectionview.

Comment: You can make custom view inside tableviewcell.

Comment: @Keyur I'm new to swift/ios, but i've been playing with tableview and collectionview.

I know how to show views inside a tableviewcell but i don't know to to build a table in a easy way. Maybe there isn't an easy way? =/

Comment: i think you should read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796835/creating-a-grid-view-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I need to put something like this inside a uitableviewcell` - do you? Why?

This isn't a very mobile friendly way to view that data. Is this something you need to do, or something you think you need to do?

Often times developers will come from other backgrounds and try to use web design on a mobile, or management will ask for something that doesn't make sense. Its up to you to take these requirements and make it work on a mobile. This doesn't always mean delivering exactly a matching picture of what was asked.

If there are varying numbers of rows, I would first of all say that each row needs to be a cell, not the entire thing as a cell. I would suggest looking at something like:

`Overall | With Managers | Pay | Holidays` - as a tableView section header (assuming it needs to be part of a bigger tableView).

and then having:

```
Middle
management     7   |    7    |    6    |   7
```

as one cell, and

```
Lower
management     7   |    7    |    6    |   7
```

as another and so on for the rest of the section.

If there will be a varying number of columns as well. I would suggest breaking it up into a master / detail style view. Where you have cells like:

```
Middle Management     >
Lower Management      >
```

and then clicking one of these will bring you to a screen with a full break down of each column (each column probably being a cell in this case).

Its never a good idea to try pack a huge amount of content into a single cell. And you should avoid at all costs having a scrollable cell.